# Get request with very long query string. (CSV)

Tags: rest, csv

I'm looking to implement an API call where you can specify any combination of up to ~6000 ids to get data from the server. Trouble is it's quite likely that a request will contain a large number of id's - say around 4000. The query string would therefore be very long and possibly too long for the browser?

I wonder, what would be the best approach? I could use a POST but it doesn't really fit with REST - but then again I'm not too fussed about that. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, POST really is the solution. From a REST perspective and also from an optimization perspective, if you expect this call to be invoked multiple times with the same list of IDs, you may want to consider one POST call to create a server-side named/defined list and then for subsequent GET requests to reference the created list so that this data doesn't have to be repeated each and every time.